# Why this PS1 script lies to check if some arguments are possible on a setup.exe?

Tags: powershell, installation, arguments

I have a PowerShell script that lies on the result, anyone know why?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 
}
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FilePath = $FileBrowser.FileName
 
$paramList = @("/S", "/s", "-s", "-S", "/silent", "/SILENT", "-silent", "-SILENT", "/quiet", "/QUIET", "-quiet", "-QUIET", "/q", "/Q", "-q", "-Q", "/qn", "/QN", "-qn", "-QN", "/passive", "/PASSIVE", "-passive", "-PASSIVE", "/qb", "/QB", "-qb", "-QB", "/qr", "/QR", "-qr", "-QR", "/norestart", "-norestart", "/NORESTART", "/VERYSILENT", "/verysilent", "-verysilent", "-VERYSILENT")
$validArgs = @()
foreach ($arg in $paramList) {
    $command = Get-Command $FilePath
    if ($command.parameters.keys -contains $arg) {
        $validArgs += $arg
    }
}
 
if ($validArgs) {
    Write-Host "Silent arguments available are : $validArgs"
} else {
    Write-Host "No silent arguments detected"
}
 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

It's to detect if these silent arguments are usable on a setup.exe

Testable on the vcredist installer for example, which contains several of these possible arguments
https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

The script is made with chatgpt, I tried some variants but no one is working.

Answer (score 2):

While [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) is capable of discovering *external programs* (`*.exe`) and reporting basic file-system metadata about them, *it knows nothing about what parameters they support* - that only works for *PowerShell-native* commands (that have formally declared parameters).

Short of invoking an executable with `-?`, `-h`, `--help` in order to invoke the command-line help - whatever parameter a given executable requires - and searching through the output, there is *no* general mechanism for discovering an executable's command-line parameters.

As an aside: PowerShell is case-*insensitive* by default, so there's no need for matching *case variations* with operators such as `-contains`; e.g., the following succeeds:

```
@('silent') -contains 'SiLenT' # -> true
```